# SQL Server collate syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, collate

I have searched using collate and am using it in the same way the answers say to use it; however, I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near 'COLLATE'

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    P.FIRST_NAME_SRCH,
    P.LAST_NAME_SRCH,
    ' ' as Title,
    CASE E.FULL_PART_TIME
       WHEN 'F' THEN 'Full Time'
       WHEN 'P' THEN 'Part Time'
       WHEN 'O' THEN 'Occasional'
       ELSE E.FULL_PART_TIME
    END AS FULL_PART_TIME,
    ' ' as Capacity,
    REPLACE(E.HOME_PHONE,'/','-') as HOMEPHONE,
    ' ' as MobilePh,
    ' ' as Email,
    CONVERT(char(10),E.BIRTHDATE,101) as 'BIRTHDATE',
    CASE 
       WHEN E.HIRE_DT > E.REHIRE_DT THEN CONVERT(char(10),E.HIRE_DT,101)
       WHEN E.REHIRE_DT > E.HIRE_DT THEN CONVERT(char(10),E.REHIRE_DT,101)
       ELSE CONVERT(char(10),E.HIRE_DT,101)
    END as 'HIRE_DT',
    ' ' as CommPref,
    RTRIM(K.LEVEL3) as 'JOBCODE',
    E.EMPLID
FROM
    HRPROD..PS_EMPLOYEES E, HRPROD..PS_PERSONAL_DATA P, TKCSDB..CTRLEVEL3CFG K
WHERE
    E.COMPANY = 'WSQ'
    AND E.EMPLID = P.EMPLID
    AND K.VAL106 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = E.JOBCODE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
ORDER BY
    P.LAST_NAME_SRCH
```

I have tried (with same syntax error)

```
AND 
   UPPER(K.VAL106) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = UPPER(E.JOBCODE) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

and (returns Cannot resolve collation conflict for equal to operation.)

```
UPPER(K.VAL106) = UPPER(E.JOBCODE)
```

What am I doing wrong in the syntax?

Comment: Perhaps that comparison is not the source of the collation conflict.

Comment: I removed that line and the query executes.  Sorry - I should have mentioned that...

Comment: What happens if you use: `UPPER(K.VAL106)  = UPPER(E.JOBCODE) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`?

Comment: Same error: Incorrect syntax near 'COLLATE'.

Comment: I have also tried to remove the UPPER statements.  Same result

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Are the E.EMPLID & P.EMPLID columns numeric. If they are not, you need to set the collation on that line too - (COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT).

Comment: I have converted from old style joins to explicit joins.  Same result.  I also verified that the EMPLID is numeric.

Comment: Move `Collate` clauses inside the `UPPER()`, right after the columns names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be a version thing.  Executing via the SQL SERVER 2012 Mgt Studio query tool returns the expected results without error.